# Estimate correlation in Python

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, pearson-correlation

I have a dataset with labels and usernames:

```
Labels   Usernames
1         Londonderry
1         Londoncalling
1          Steveonder43
0         Maryclare_re
1         Patent107391
0         Anonymous 
1         _24londonqr
...
```

I would need to show there is a correlation between usernames containing the word London and label 1.  To do it, I created a second label to see where the word London was

```
for idx, username in df['Usernames']:
    if 'London' in username:
        df['London'].iloc[idx] = 1
    else:
        df['London'].iloc[idx] = 0
```

Then I compared these binary variables, using Pearson correlation coefficient:

```
import scipy.stats.pearsonr as rho
corr = rho(df['labels'], df['London'])
```

However it does not work.
Am I missing something in the above steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `Labels` in your dataframe but you pass `labels`, also I enhance the code by `contains`

```
df['London'] = df['Usernames'].str.contains('London').astype(int)
from scipy import stats
stats.pearsonr(df['Labels'], df['London'])
Out[12]: (0.4, 0.37393392381774704)
```